# How do I connect to a local API via react/formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, formik

me and my business partner is coming up with a basic coding model for our respective fields.  He's backend, while I'll be doing front end.  He made a test api with endpoints that I'm trying to connect to via React/Axios/Formik.  I tested to make sure that the endpoints work in postman, and they do, so now I just have to properly code it on my end.  Yet I seem to be having trouble.  I keep getting a "NET::ERR_SSL_Protocol_Error" when ever I try to make a post via a login/register component I built.  Here is the code for each relevant component:

Update:

Thanks to a user here, I managed to get rid of that pesky SSL error.  Now I'm getting a 400 status.  I'm not sure how to pass in data to a api via formik.  Here's the updated code for registration below:

SignUp.js

```
// import React, {useState} from "react";
// import axiosWithAuth from "../utilils/axiosWithAuth";
// import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

// const initialState = {
//     username: "",
//     password: "",
//     email: "",
//     role: ""
//   };

//   // const initialFormErrors = {
//   //   username: "",
//   //   password: "",
//   // };
  


// const Registration = (props) => {
 

//     const  { push } = useHistory();

//     const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialState);
//     // const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState(initialFormErrors);
//     // const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(togDisabled);
    



//   const handleChange = e => {
//    const name = e.target.name;
//    const value = e.target.value;
//     setState({
//         ...state.credentials,
//         [name]:value
//     });
//   setFormValues({
//      ...formValues,
//       [name]:value
//   });
// };

//   const register = e => {
//     e.preventDefault();
//     const signUpData = {
//         username: formValues.name,
//         password: formValues.password,
//         email: formValues.email,
//         role: formValues.role
        
//     }
//       axiosWithAuth()
//       .post("/api/auth/register", signUpData)
//       .then((res) => {
//         console.log(res);
//         push("/login");
//       })
//       .catch(err =>
//         console.error("bk: SignUp.js: Registration: err.message: ", err.message)
//       );
//   };


//     return (
//       <div>
//         <form onSubmit={register}>
//         <div>
//          <label>Username</label>
//           <input
//             type="text"
//             name="username"
//             value={formValues.name}
//             onChange={handleChange}
//           /> </div>
//           <div>
//          <label>Password</label>
//           <input
//             type="password"
//             name="password"
//             value={formValues.password}
//             onChange={handleChange}
//           /></div>
//           <div>
//          <label>Email</label>
//            <input
//             type="email"
//             name="email"
//             value={formValues.email}
//             onChange={handleChange}
//           /></div>
//           <div>
//          <label>Role</label>
//            <input
//             type="text"
//             name="role"
//             value={formValues.role}
//             onChange={handleChange}
//           /></div>
//           <button>Sign Up</button>
//         </form>
//       </div>
//     );
//   }

// export default Registration;

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axiosWithAuth from '../utilils/axiosWithAuth';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Formik, Form} from 'formik';
import FormikControl from '../Forms/FormikControl';

const Registration = (props) => {

  const { push } = useHistory();



    const initialValues = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        email: '',
        role:''
    }
    
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialValues);

    const validate = values => {
        let errors = {}

        //If each of the values are not valid return a required text, otherwise return null. 
        
       if (!values.username) { errors.username = 'required' };
       if (!values.password) { errors.password = 'required' };
       if (!values.email) { errors.email = 'required' };
       if (!values.role) { errors.role = 'required' };

       return errors;
    }


    const onSubmit = (values) => {
      console.log('form data', values);
         axiosWithAuth()
      .post("/api/auth/register", state )
      .then(res => {
        setState(res.values)
        push("/login");
      })
      .catch(err =>
        console.error("bk: Login.js: Register: err.message: ", err.message)
      );
    }
   
    return (
        <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validate={validate}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        >
        {formik => (
            <Form>
                <FormikControl 
                control='input'
                type='text'
                label='Username'
                name='username'
                // value={initialValues.username}
                />
                    <FormikControl 
                control='input'
                type='password'
                label='Password'
                name='password'
                // value={initialValues.password}
                />

                    <FormikControl 
                control='input'
                type='email'
                label='Email'
                name='email'
                // value={initialValues.email}
                />

                    <FormikControl 
                control='input'
                type='text'
                label='Role'
                name='role'
                // value={initialValues.role}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </Form>
        )}    
        </Formik>
    )
}

export default Registration;
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axiosWithAuth from '../utilils/axiosWithAuth';
import setToken from '../utilils/';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Formik, Form} from 'formik';
import FormikControl from '../Forms/FormikControl';

const Login = (props) => {

  const { push } = useHistory();

    const initialValues = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
      
    }

    const validate = values => {
        let errors = {}
        
        //If each of the values are not valid return a required text, otherwise return null. 
        if (!values.username) { errors.username = 'required' };
       if (!values.password) { errors.password = 'required' };

       return errors;
        
    }
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {

      const loginData = {
        username: initialValues.username ,
        password: initialValues.password
      }

      axiosWithAuth()
      .post("/api/auth/login", loginData)
      .then(res => {
        setToken(res.data.token);
        push("/protected");
      })
      .catch(err =>
        console.error("bk: Login.js: login: err.message: ", err.message)
      );
    }

    return (
        <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validate={validate}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        
        >
        {formik => (
            <Form>
                <FormikControl 
                control='input'
                type='text'
                label='Username'
                name='username'
                
                />
                    <FormikControl 
                control='input'
                type='password'
                label='Password'
                name='password'
                
                />

               
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </Form>
        )}    
        </Formik>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

axiosWithAuth.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosWithAuth = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  return axios.create({
    
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000"
  });
};

export default axiosWithAuth;
```

tokenStore.js

```
const tokenState = "";

//
export const getToken = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem(tokenState);
};

//
export const setToken = (newToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem(tokenState, newToken);
};

//
export const clearToken = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem(tokenState);
};
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { getToken } from './tokenStore';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...props }) => {

  const token = getToken();


  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render = {() => {
          return token ? <Component />: <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from './Components/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './utilils/PrivateRoute';
import Registration from './Components/SignUp';
import DevPage from './Pages/Dev';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router >
    <div>
    <nav>
          <Link to="/login">Login </Link>
          <Link to="/SignUP">SignUp </Link>
          <Link to="/protected"> Dev</Link>
    </nav>
    <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute 
        path="/protected"
        component={DevPage} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />    
        <Route exact path="/SignUP"><Registration/></Route>
        <Route component={Login} />
    </Switch>        
    </div> 
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I plan on refactoring the code in ContextAPI once the tests turn out successful.  All I'm asking for here is validation that the code is proper and to fill in the blanks of what I'm missing or what I need to correct.  Let me know if you need the backend code as well and I'll add that in future edits.  Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling httpS://localhost:8000 in axiosWithAuth.js, the error is for an invalid or inexistent SSL certificate. Call http://localhost:8000 while you're in development and make sure to transition to https when you know where you're hosting this thing and have a valid url and ssl certificate

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you.  That got rid of the SSL error, but now I get a 400 error.  Still, that's definitely a step up.

Comment: A 400 error is a bad request from the client. Now that you know you're getting through to your backend, try a console.log on the server side to see what is coming from your frontend and take it from there.